# Процентное зависимое выравнивание

Tags: html, css

Не могу выровнять с помощью "left:100%/top:100%" два блока относительно границ таблицы. Почему выравнивание идет по непонятным границам обёртки "wrapper" вместо выравнивания таблицы?
Нижний блок "+" должен быть выровнен под левой нижней ячейкой таблицы (примерно, не учитывая border), правый блок "+" должен быть выровнен справа от верхней правой ячейки таблицы. 
По какой причине выходит так как выходит?

```css
html, body{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}

.wrapper{ 
 margin:51px;
}

.tab_small{   
 border: 1px solid #48aae6;
 position: relative; 
 border-spacing: 2px;
 margin-top: 43px;
}

.tab_small td{ 
 background-color: #48aae6; 
}

.box{ 
 height: 48px;
 width: 48px;
}

.opt_buttons{ 
 display: flex;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 font: caption; 
 font-size: 24px;
 color: white;
}

.plus{
 position:absolute;
 background-color: #f3a500;
}

.bottom_plus{
 top: 100%;
 left: 0%
}

.right_plus{ 
 left: 100%;
 top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<table class="tab_small">
  <tbody id="str">
   <tr class="col">
    <td class="box"></td>
    <td class="box"></td>
    <td class="box"></td>
    <td class="box"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="col">
    <td class="box"></td>
    <td class="box"></td>
    <td class="box"></td>
    <td class="box"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="col">
    <td class="box"></td>
    <td class="box"></td>
    <td class="box"></td>
    <td class="box"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="col">
    <td class="box"></td>
    <td class="box"></td>
    <td class="box"></td>
    <td class="box"></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>   
 </table>
 <div class="plus bottom_plus opt_buttons">+</div>
 <div class="plus right_plus opt_buttons">+</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Чтобы relative-absolute работало нужно чтобы абсолютно спозиционированный элемент был вложен в таблицу. Либо, если возможно, был псевдоэлементом.

Comment: мне нужно выровнять не сколько относительно таблицы, сколько относительно всего общего контейнера. таблица и блок принадлежат одному родительскому контейнеру, почему в данном случае границы общего контейнера не зависят от его наполнения?

Comment: Тогда почему вы таблице даете `position: relative`? Это нужно задать тому элементу, относительно которого вы хотите спозиционировать абсолюбно вложенные в него элементы.

Answer (score 1):

Не забываем, что кроме `top` и `left`, есть ещё `right` и `bottom` ;-)
Ну и `calc()` в помощь (благо, давно поддерживается):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  min-height: 312px;
  min-width: 312px;
}

.tab_small {
  border: 1px solid #48aae6;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}

.tab_small td {
  background-color: #48aae6;
}

.box {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
}

.opt_buttons {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font: caption;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.plus {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f3a500;
}

.bottom_plus {
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.right_plus {
  right: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="tab_small">
    <tbody id="str">
      <tr class="col">
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="col">
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="col">
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="col">
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="plus right_plus opt_buttons">+</div>
  <div class="plus bottom_plus opt_buttons">+</div>
</div>
```